# Rotate copies: create index for watch?

Tags: inkscape

I wish to create a watch index picture with Inkscape.

I know I can use LPE's *Rotate copies* function, but somehow I can't find the correct values.

I wish to rotate this little red rectangle at 30 degree:

[image]

Facts:

- Image is in pixel unit everywhere.
- This bar is roughly 4*10px
- This bar's center point is exactly at `x=225, y=4`.
- I wish to have 12 copies (technically 12 bars, so 11 copies)
- I wish to have the 6th bar positioned at exactly `x=225, y=221`.
- There is a guide at 225 on both horizontal and vertical axis

I tried creating 12 copies, but it's not getting *rectangular* shape:

[image]

Not to mention, that *origin* is pretty weird to reach this result:

[image]

How can I do this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LPE Rotate Copies effect.

1. Draw a short line using the pen tool, and apply a stroke to it
2. In the Effects Panel, click the + button to add a new Path Effect
3. In the LPE Selector, choose the Rotate Copies LPE

[image]

You will get something like this

[image]

4. Switch to the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool <kbd>N</kbd>
5. Click and drag the centre origin control, holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you drag will constrain the move vertically

[image]

6. In the Path Effects panel, set the number of copies to 12

[image]

7. If you want to add a blur, add it in the Fill and Strokes panel

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the path-effect, you can try the 'Object → Align and Distribute...' panel switched to the 'Circular' tab.

Just manually make duplicates of your object (or make one clone with <kbd>Alt + D</kbd> and duplicate that – exclude the original when arranging), then either add a circle-object to your selection or enter the parameters into the dialog and click 'Arrange'.

[image: 'Align and Distribute' panel example]

The reason why the 'Rotate Copies' path-effect wasn't working correctly is probably because you resized your object in a way that added a `transform`-attribute.

When you use the scale-handles in select mode on an object that has a filter applied (or just move the object, which is why the origin was acting "weird" too), instead of manipulating the object directly, it sets the new scale as a `transform`, which influences path-effects as well:

[image: Path-effect affected by the 'transform' attribute]

If you scale the object before applying the blur, or use the tool corresponding to the object type (rectangle tool for rectangles, node tool for paths, etc.), you manipulate the object directly and avoid setting a `transform`.

[image]

Comment: What do you think, why path-effects are not working?

Comment: @Daniel You probably scaled the original object in a way that added a ```transform```-attribute, meaning the path-effect was stretched as well.

Comment: @Daniel The Rotate Copies LPE is certainly working. [see example](https://imgur.com/pWRqGLe). Not sure what is wrong with your example.

Comment: @Xrott: if I do this with *text*, can I somehow control the starting angle? (I created a text "60" at 12, and copied it (05,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55). Your recommended method can arrange these texts, however 60 is now at 3, i.e. 90 degrees rotated during arrange. Can I prevent that?

Comment: @Daniel You can't rotate the placement of numbers without rotating the characters. Just place them manually. It will be easier.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, you simply set the 'Angle X/Y' to what you need. In your case it should be something like ```-60.0°``` to ```300.0°```. [Example](https://imgur.com/RL3wwkg). Also, why did you accept the answer, that you said didn't work for you?

Comment: @Xrott: I started from scratch, and then LPE worked as I wanted, and when I need 60 instances it's simpler than manual copying, sorry.

Comment: @Daniel It didn't even address what was wrong with your first attempt though, and just reiterated what you already did, only accidentally excluding the thing that broke it. I've updated my answer explaining why it didn't work for you the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution "Align and Distribute...", but Inkscape 1.2 crashed.
A very powerful solution is the following way. Install the extension "Simple Inkscape Scripting", see [https://inkscape.org/~pakin/%E2%98%85simple-inkscape-scripting](https://inkscape.org/%7Epakin/%E2%98%85simple-inkscape-scripting)

Write a simple program like the following one:

```
import math
canvas.true_width = 390
canvas.true_height = 390
canvas.viewbox = [0, 0, 390, 390]

x_c = 195
y_c = 195
r_max = 195 
circle((x_c, y_c), r_max, fill='#000000', stroke_width=0)

r = r_max - 14
r_minute = r - 4

for m in range(60):
    if m % 5 != 0:
        w = m * math.pi / 30
        x = x_c + int(cos(w) * r_minute)
        y = y_c + int(sin(w) * r_minute)
        circle((x, y), 2, fill='#ffffff', stroke_width=0)

r1 = r_max - 50
for m in range(12):
    w = m * math.pi / 6
    x1 = x_c + int(cos(w) * r1)
    y1 = y_c + int(sin(w) * r1)
    x2 = x_c + int(cos(w) * r)
    y2 = y_c + int(sin(w) * r)
    line((x1, y1), (x2, y2), stroke='#ffffff', stroke_width=4)
```

So you have full control. This simple example results in the following watch face:

[image]