# How do you rotate the position of multiple objects without rotating the objects themselves in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, transform

I have a set of objects that are placed a certain way and now I want to rotate the whole arrangement. However, if I use the transform-handles it changes the orientation of the objects as well:

[image: Multiple objects after rotation.]

How can I rotate the placement, while keeping the individual objects the right way up?

(This question and answer was inspired by [a comment on this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/159547))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done very easily with the 'Object → Transform...' panel.

First switch to the 'Rotate'-tab, set the angle and make sure 'Apply to each object separately' is unchecked. Then click 'Apply':

[image: Objects after first rotation, angled in the wrong direction]

Now simply switch the direction with the buttons under the 'Angle' input, *enable* the 'Apply to each object separately' setting this time and click 'Apply' again:

[image: Objects after second adjustment, facing the correct way]

By the way, this works with all kinds of object types, including text-objects, and can also be done using the other transform modes like 'Skew' or 'Scale' (using percentages in that case).